# NPM not working globally

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-7

I am using window 7 and i can not use npm globally.
My system is admin protected PC.I can not run as administrator my command prompt.
I tried to set path i.e.,

```
set NODE_PATH %AppData%\npm\node_modules
```

but it did not work.please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try setting your `PATH` variable in your command prompt as given below,

```
set path=%PATH%;c:\Users\[YOUR_USER_ACCOUNT_DIRECTORY]\AppData\Roaming\npm;
```

**Edit:** Yes you can,

Navigate to Control Panel => User Accounts => User Accounts and do the following steps,

[image: Follow the steps]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much, it was so easy. I wasted a whole day.

Comment: But its working for current session only.Is there any way to set for future?.

Comment: @Animay Check out my updated answer and follow those steps.